# Building Release Version of IOS APP in Visual Studio 2013 Cordova Overriding Provisioning Profile

Tags: ios, cordova, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

I have written an IOS app using Visual Studio 2013 / Cordova and am trying to create a release build, using my organisation's Enterprise Distribution Certificate / Provisioning Profile.

On the 'build' Mac I have valid development and distribution certificates / provisioning profiles, but each time I build the Release version of the app, the build agent selects the development provisioning profile rather than the one for distribution.

I have tried to force VS to use the Distribution profile by adding a build-release.xcconfig file as outlined [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/blob/master/bin/templates/scripts/cordova/build-release.xcconfig) , including it in my solution's res/native/ios folder, but it still uses the dev profile.  I have resorted to building the app in xcode and selecting the Code Signing Identity / Provisioning Profile manually (which creates the build ok).

Has anybody any tips on how to get this working?

Comment: Which version of Tools for Apache Cordova are you using? These instructions should work properly with CTP3.1 but may not work prior to that. Also, have you overridden the Cordova version?

Comment: Hi Chuck, I am using VS2013 CTP3.1, Cordova is v4.2.0 .  I have placed a  build-release.xccconfig in the res/native/ios folder only (as per instructions here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/dn757048.aspx#iOS . Based on this article I have assumed VS will handle the override of the cordova version for me - how can I check this?

Comment: Can you post your build-release.xcconfig contents?  Also, it may be obvious, but I assume you are using the Release or Distribution configurations, correct?  (Debug will always use the developer profile.)

Comment: The contents are exactly the same as the config at:- https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/blob/master/bin/templates/scripts/cordova/build-release.xcconfig  - do I need to tailor this to my specific identity / provisioning profile?

Comment: That is indeed strange. Your build should be failing completely if it's not matching a distribution certificate for the Release or Distribution configurations even without xcconfig file. If you remove the custom xcconfig file, does this happen?  I've verified the behavior against CTP3.1 and VS 2015 RC.  To verify your xcconfig file is getting copied across, add a comment to the file, and then after you build, go to remote-builds/builds/<build number>/cordovaApp/platforms/ios on your Mac.  <build number> should be visible in the output window and check the file.